# Math in Nuclear Reactor

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, computational-physics, nuclear-engineering

I don’t understand the meaning of equations in nuclear reactor physics. How do I learn the relevant content? Those complicated formulas and symbols often confuse me. How can I learn reactor physics well? Help baby!

Answer (score 2):

Well you could read overviews of reactor physics (search using google) or seeif you can find an online schools like Udemy, Edx, or others (again search for online reactor courses). But to really understand it you'll need to understand the math. Reactor Physics, like all physics involves much math.

I just found a course by Edx on the basics of physics reactors. It can be found here. https://www.edx.org/course/nuclear-reactor-physics-basics.

And lastly you should take university courses on Reactors. Probably taught by engineering Dept. There is probably a series of course that will bring you up to speed.